# Make Text View and label as right aligned in UITableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, alignment, chat

I want to make timelabel , userlabel and textstring rightaligned in cell.  So that when receiver send some message then it will displayed as right in chat application .

How can i do that?

My code is as below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CHAT_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
if (row < chatData.count)
{
    NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:TEXT];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize size = [chatText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(225.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    cell.textString.frame = CGRectMake(75, 14, size.width +20, size.height + 20); // set text frame
    cell.textString.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];        // set text font
    cell.textString.text = chatText;                                              // set text
    [cell.textString sizeToFit];
    NSDate *theDate = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:DATE];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:DATE_FORMAT];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;                                       // set timeLabel to display date and time
    cell.userLabel.text = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:NAME]; // set userLabel to display userName
    if ([self.user.userName isEqualToString:cell.userLabel.text]) {
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleSomeone.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:21 topCapHeight:14]];
    }
    else
    {
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleMine.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:21 topCapHeight:14]];
    }
}
return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:TEXT];
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(225.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
return labelSize.height + 40;
}
```

For this i think i have to align frame as right..How can i align rightalignment to frame??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:
cell.textString.frame = CGRectMake(75, 14, size.width +20, size.height + 20);

set your x origin (75) to (tableView.frame.size.width - size.width) (+20 if needed)
which means go to the rightest point, than back as much as needed for the text width and put the text there.
Hope i was clear.